# How to setup Azure DevOps Server 2019 with LDAP

Tags: active-directory, ldap, azure-devops-server-2019

I am trying to connect our Azure Devops Server 2019 to our external Active Directory. I have no experience with LDAP, connecting to an AD or similar.

It should be possible for users to log on to the Azure DevOps Server with their AD credentials.

Unfortunately I cannot find a way to do this. Is this possible with LDAP? And if so, how? 
Are there any other possibilities besides integrating the Azure DevOps Server into the Active Directory domain (this will not be possible with us)?

I would be very grateful for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid that Azure DevOps Server/TFS only supports AD. You need to add your Azure DevOps Server/TFS to your corporate domain, and establish trust between your corporate domain and the external domain.

[image]

You may take a look at the blog below:

http://blogs.agorainc.com/post/External-User-in-Team-Foundation-Server-(TFS)-with-Active-Directory.aspx

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I was afraid this was the only way it would work. 
Unfortunately the link you have provided is broken and I get a 500 server error.

Comment: Hi Zordak, in the past I succesfully configured TFS 2017 on premises in a domain A trusted with a domain B; I succeed in login users from domain B. Now I'm trying to setup Azure DevOps Server 2019 update 1.1 with same domains A and B thats is the same configuration described by Cece Dong. Unfortunately I have problem already described here https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1119427/how-resolve-error-some-or-all-identity-references.html. Coud you help me? Did you succeed in access to blogs.agorainc.com post?

Comment: Found using https://cachedview.com/ that is http://web.archive.org/web/20191224143934/http://blogs.agorainc.com/post/External-User-in-Team-Foundation-Server-(TFS)-with-Active-Directory.aspx